# Given an circular array calculate the diff between two consecutive number. & if diff is greater than ‘k’, print 1 else print 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

Given  an circular array & calculate the diff  between two consecutive number. & if diff is greater than ‘k’, print 1 else print 0

Input Description:
You are given two numbers ‘n’, ’m’. Next line contains n space separated integers.

Output Description:
Print 1 if the difference is greater than ‘m’.

Can Anyone help with the code for easy Understanding for beginners

Sample Input :

```
5 15
50 65 85 98 35
```

Sample Output :

```
0 1 0 1 0
```

Code:

```
let cirluarArray = (data) => {
    let n=data[0].split(" ").map(Number);//(sample input 1)
    let arr = data[1].split(" ").map(Number);//(sample input 2)
    let i,arr1=[];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
        let x=arr[i]-arr[i+1];
        if((x>0 && x<n[1])||(x<0 && x>-n[1])){
            arr1.push(0);
        }
        else{
            arr1.push(1);
        }
    }
    if(((arr[arr.length-1]-arr[0])>0 && (arr[arr.length-1]-arr[0])<n[1])||((arr[arr.length-1]-arr[0])<0 && (arr[arr.length-1]-arr[0])>-n[1])){
        arr1.push(0);
    }
    else{
        arr1.push(1);
    }
    return arr1.join(" ");
};
console.log(cirluarArray(userInput));
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are attempting this in JS? Also, Your question was horrendously formatted. I have submitted an edit for it. 

also, what is held in data? is that just a string with numbers separated by a space? Is 'n' and 'm' part of the numbers in data? Or is data just the array elements?

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion brother, here data is the array elements kindly help me via code if possible .

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @jraufeisen Given an circular array & calculate the diff between two consecutive number. sample input is [50 65 85 98 35]

Comment: @slystersanto Where are you getting values of n and m if data is only the array elements? How do you know those values?

Comment: @jraufeisen thanks a lot dear brother:)this is santhosh from india last month only i started my full stack developer course and i am a beginner too, and i have no idea about JS and this is my first experience ever to start writing codes once thanks for the help brother,keep in touch brother this is humble request.

Comment: i can get the values from sample input brother,here 5 & 15 represents n and m

Comment: @jraufeisen Brother kindly let me know exactly where to apply my array values if possible please post a code with my given sample input and output.this is my first code so i don't know where to use my sample input and output.

Comment: @jraufeisen thanks a lot dear brother its working awesome love you man:)cheers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is

```js
    const circularArray = (array, k) => {
        array.push(array.at(0)); // circular array
        let output = [];
        
        for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            const currentNumber = array[i];
            const prevNumber = array[i-1];
    
            let diff = currentNumber - prevNumber;
            if (diff < 0) {
                diff *= -1; // if negative, change to positive
            }
            
            if (diff > k) {
                output.push(1);
            } else {
                output.push(0);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    const result = circularArray([50, 65, 85, 98, 35], 15);
    console.log(result);
```